# Serilog.AspNetCore library not working in terminal

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I want to use the serilog library by integrating it into my project.
dotnet add package Serilog.AspNetCore

Install the package and put it in Program.cs

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
             Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                 .UseSerilog()
                 .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                 {
                     webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                 });
```

After adding UseSerilog() I type `Dotnet watch run` in terminal. Project `Building...` remains .
I am posting a sample project
https://github.com/bayramerenn/SerilogTest

Comment: Do you add any sink?

Comment: Yes I have added sql in my live project. The result is still the same

Comment: Use Serilog's example as reference: https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore/tree/dev/samples/Sample

Comment: Yes, it worked when I did as in the example, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Paste the code into program.cs. You can then run the project from terminal

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseSerilog((context, services, configuration) => configuration
                    .ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration)
                    .ReadFrom.Services(services)
                    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                    .WriteTo.Console())
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => { webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>(); });
```